# Any DI Frameworks that convert from string to constructor Types?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I'm just wondering if there is a DI Framework for .net that handles string-to-some type conversion for me?

Basically I have this constructor:

```
public MyImplTwo(bool someParam)
```

and a string like "true" or "1". I've tried Unity, but this throws an error saying that no constructor with the signature MyImplTwo(string) exists:

```
container.RegisterType<MyImplBase, MyImplTwo>(new InjectionConstructor(new object[] {"true"}));
```

Is there one? Essentially I mainly need a wrapper around Activator.CreateInstance, so I'm looking for the simplest IoC that works. On the other hand, I wouldn't mind the extra functionality of the "big" containers as long as the above works.

*Edit:* I can get the desired type as a string as well, and if required also the argumentName. The things I cannot do is a) have a container-specific config file (configuration is done through a database) and b) decorate the classes that should be resolved with any attributes as I don't control them.

Comment: I updated Mark's answer with link to Windsor docs, explaining how to do it w/o any form of XML config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the edit in your question, I'd say [Castle Windsor](http://castleproject.org/container/index.html) should be able to address your needs.

Using Windsor's XML configuration, you can specify primitive parameter values, e.g.

```
<component id="myImp"
           service="MyImplBase, MyAssembly"
           type="MyImplTwo, MyOtherAssembly">
    <parameters>
        <someParam>true</someParam>
    </parameters>
</component>
```

Windsor doesn't require you to put the XML configuration in an application configuration file. You can **read it from any XML stream**, including from a database. Here's a code snippet that shows how to read XML configuration from an XML string:

```
string myXml = // read XML from a custom resource...

var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(
    new ConfigurationInstaller(
        new XmlInterpreter(
            new StaticContentResource(myXml))));
```

You can now use `container` to resolve `MyImplBase` and it will return an instance of `MyImplTwo` with `someParam` set to `true`.

Also with Windsor [you can pass dependencies as strings to the fluent registration API](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Inline-Dependencies.ashx#Supplying_XML-like_parameters_2), and conversion subsystem in Windsor will convert them for you, which completely eliminates need for any form of XML config.

Comment: more precisely Windsor has a conversion subsystem that implements `ITypeConverter` that does all this stuff

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, System.Boolean does not have a constructor that will allow it to be instantiated with Activator.CreateInstance. You'll probably have to use Boolean.Parse() or Boolean.TryParse().

I don't know of any IO frameworks that do what you want, but could you perhaps just work with your preferred framework, like so... (using [Autofac](http://autofac.googlecode.com/), for example):

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyImplTwo>()
    .As<MyImplBase>()
    .WithParameter("someParam", Boolean.Parse(yourStringHere));
```

or, for types that you can instantiate with Activator.CreateInstance:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyImplTwo>()
    .As<MyImplBase>()
    .WithParameter("someOtherParam", Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("TypeName"), new object[] { }));
```

Edit:
Another option would be to extend a DI framework of your choosing, and combine it with some string serialization functionality.

For example, using [Autofac](http://autofac.googlecode.com/) with [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), we can create the extension method:

```
static class AutofacExtensions
{
    public static IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>
        WithSerializedParameter<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle>(
            this IRegistrationBuilder<TLimit, TReflectionActivatorData, TStyle> registration, 
            string parameterName, 
            string typeName, 
            string value) 
        where TReflectionActivatorData : ReflectionActivatorData
    {
        return registration.WithParameter(parameterName, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value, Type.GetType(typeName)));
    }
}
```

And use the extension method as follows:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyImplTwo>()
    .As<MyImplBase>()
    .WithSerializedParameter("someParam", "System.Boolean", "true");
```